# Building a 3d plot function for Antenna Emission Measurements

Tags: r, 3d

I have an input of three [1:360,2] tables that include measurements of the three planes X,Y,Z with each plane having 1:360 degree polar coordinates. A good example of one of those tables being the image here.
[image example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/antenna/win64/xxpolarpattern_helix.png)

I would like to print those three "circles" as different planes circles (x,y,z) as is shown in the link below. 
[click here](https://imgur.com/a/C6thy)

I wrote last night a small example that works on the rgl library (but perhaps 
I should "move" this code to the ggplot2) that plots those three circles by converting the polar coordinates to cartesian ones, for simplicity assume that all three circles have radius of 1. You can copy paste the below and see what I mean

```
require("rgls")

degreeToRadian<-function(degree){
  return   (0.01745329252*degree)
}

turnPolarToX<-function(Amplitude,Coordinate){
  return (Amplitude*cos(degreeToRadian(Coordinate)))
}

turnPolarToY<-function(Amplitude,Coordinate){
  return (Amplitude*sin(degreeToRadian(Coordinate)))
}

# first circle
X1<-turnPolarToX(1,1:360)
Y1<-turnPolarToY(1,1:360)
Z1<-rep(0,360)

# second circle
X2<-turnPolarToX(1,1:360)
Y2<-rep(0,360)
Z2<-turnPolarToY(1,1:360)

# third circle
X3<-rep(0,360)
Y3<-turnPolarToX(1,1:360)
Z3<-turnPolarToY(1,1:360)

Min<-min(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3)
Max<-max(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,X3,Y3,Z3)
plot3d(X1,Y1,Z1,xlim=c(Min,Max),ylim=c(Min,Max),zlim=c(Min,Max),box=TRUE,axe=FALSE,add=TRUE,col="red",type="l")
plot3d(X2,Y2,Z2,xlim=c(Min,Max),ylim=c(Min,Max),zlim=c(Min,Max),box=TRUE,axe=FALSE,add=TRUE,col="green",type="l")
plot3d(X3,Y3,Z3,xlim=c(Min,Max),ylim=c(Min,Max),zlim=c(Min,Max),box=TRUE,axe=TRUE,add=FALSE,col="blue",type="l")
```

the problem I have now is that the axes contain cartesian coordinate values that are not understandable by the user. I am thinking of how I can remove the cartesian coordinates and use colors that considers the amplitude value (of the initial information at polar corrdinates) of each vector instead of the x,y values)

I would like to thank you in advance for your reply
Regards
Alex